# Get JMSMessageID Spring

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

I am sending JMS message:

```
jmsTemplate.send("COM.YA.ADAPTER.AFM.TEST.OUT", session -> {
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
            return message;
        });
```

And want to get answer in another thread:

```
TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) jmsTemplate.receiveSelected("COM.YA.ADAPTER.AFM.TEST.IN",
                    "JMSCorrelationID='" + msgID + "'");
```

Send function doesn't return messageid. Where I can find it?
UP:
Just found a solution

```
 Session session = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection().createSession();
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
    jmsTemplate.send(AntiFraudRq, new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return message;
        }
    });
    LOGGER.error(message.getJMSMessageID());
```

But is it normal to create a session each time?

Comment: You could try a CachingConnectionFactory to prevent a new connection to IBM MQ each time.

Comment: Ok. Tnx. But can I use global Session object?

Comment: A JMS Session is 'a single-threaded context' so you need to make sure there is only one thread using a session. If your application is really single-threaded, you can reuse this session as global object. More likely you have different threads, for example one producer thread and it could then use one session for all it's sends.